# Truncate sublists to the lowest length

Tags: python

I have:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[3,4],[1,6,8,3]]
```

I want:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[1,6]]
```

Which is the list `l` with all sublists truncated to the lowest length found for the sublists in `l`.

I tried:

```
min = 1000

for x in l:
    if len(x) < min: min = len(x)

r = []

for x in l:
    s = []
    for i in range(min):
        s.append(x[i])
    r.append(s.copy())
```

Which works but quite slow and long to write. I'd like to make this more efficient through list comprehension or similar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With list comprehension, one-liner:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[3,4],[1,6,8,3]]

print ([[s[i] for i in range(min([len(x) for x in l]))] for s in l])
```

Or:

```
print ([s[:min([len(s) for s in l])] for s in l])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 6]]
```

We compute the minimal length of subslists in the 'range()' to iterate over sublists for that amount and to reconstruct a new subslist. The top-level list comprehension allows to reconstruct the nested sublist.

If you have a large nested list, you should use this version with two lines:

```
m = min([len(x) for x in l])

print ([[s[i] for i in range(m)] for s in l])
```

Or:

```
print ([s[:m] for s in l])
```

Using zip and preserving the list objects:

```
print (list([list(x) for x in zip(*zip(*l))]))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 6]]
```

Comment: One lines are not always better. This repeatedly (and unnecessarily) computes the minimum length

Comment: Your first version is very inefficient, as it recalculates the min length of all sublists for every sublist. The second one still is, though a bit less, as it uses list comprehensions instead of simply slicing (which is much faster).

Answer (score 1):

You can find the length of each item in the list and then pick min element from it. Later you can use this value to truncate all the items in the list

```
l = [[1,2,3],[3,4],[1,6,8,3]]
min_length  = min(map(len,l)) # using map with len function to get the length of each item and then using min to find the min value.
l = [item[:min_length] for item in l] # list comprehension to truncate the list
```

**One liner -**

```
l = [item[:min(map(len,l))] for item in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

One fun thing about `zip` is `zip` is the inverse itself, so `list(zip(*zip(*x)))` gives `x` in *similar* structure. 
And `zip` stop iteration when any input is exhausted.

Though the results are `tuple`s and the nested lists are not truncated in-place., one can make use of this to build the following output:

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 6)]
```

```py
l = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 6, 8, 3]]

print(list(zip(*zip(*l))))
```

Comment: Beat me to it (I did `[*map(list, zip(*zip(*l)))]`).

Answer (score 1):

Using `del`:

```
n = min(map(len, l))
for a in l:
    del a[n:]
```

Comment: That's risky. You're mutating the original list which might not be wanted. Judging by the code, the OP is crrating a new list

Comment: @Tomerikoo I know, and that's intentional. I think I'm the only one truly "truncating" the sublists, which is what they're asking for. Everybody else is copying slices.

Comment: As I said, from the OP's code it also seems they want to create new lists. That would usually be the case as you might want to use the original list at dome later point. I think it's worth noting that fact

Comment: @Tomerikoo To clarify: I don't mean that they definitely mean it the way I'm taking it and that everyone else is wrong, just that I might very well be right. I wouldn't take the OP's code as reference, they're even creating copies of their *temporary* lists for no apparent reason, which to me looks like they copied together some code from elsewhere and might not really know what they're doing :-)